# Get data from Raspberry PI over Websocket into Web Page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, raspberry-pi

I am new at web developing and I want to do webpage for remote controlling my Raspberry PI. On raspberry I have few sensors attached and I can get data by sending request on 192.168.1.100:9997. There is code written in Python. Everything works if I try to get data with Putty for example. Now I want to establish TCP connection for reading data over my webpage. I was searching for few days and found that this is possible by creating Websockets. There are many tools, most described I found is Node.js. As I understand with Node.js is possible to create Websockets and it can also serves webpage (instead of Appache for example)?

For example I am running this Websocket server just for reading data from RPi in "server.js". Now I don't know how can I get this data from "server.js" into my .html? I didn't find any very basic examples. I can get data via database, but this is not what I want. I also want to send request from my Webpage to Rpi and then read the answer.

I hope you understand my problem. If you can point me in some good examples or tell me how it must be done I will be very glad. I want to do this with Javasrcipt if it's possible.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I have now working example with Node.js, but I don't know how to implement this into my Web page that user can trigger this part of codes from .html, and show answered data into .html web page. I hope this helps.

```
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(9997, '192.168.1.100', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    //sending request
    //THIS SHOULD BE TRIGGERED FROM HTML onclick for example
    client.write('$DATA');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    //THIS DATA SHOULD BE SHOWN IN HTML for example
    //client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: you can build an Web API on top of your python code.

Comment: Amm... I think there might be some mixup - Websockets is a specific web protocol, like HTTP or SMTP or IMAP... Does your `192.168.1.100:9997` service support the Websockets protocol? does it use HTTP? does it use a  custom protocol on a raw TCP/IP connection? ...  More data is needed in order to help you out here.

Comment: Yes, probably, there are lots of new termins there...my service is TCP server, who recieves and sends ASCII data. For example I create TCP client, connect on 192.168.1.100:9997 and on request $DATA I get response $TEMP, 123, HUMIDITY, 234, etc. I just need some mechanisem that I will be able to communicate with this service from my Web Page. So far I am using Apache service for main.php page I have got MySql database implemented. I found examples that uses Node.js for asynchronous TCP clinets. I want onClick event from .html send request and show recieved data in .html. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

For getting data off a Pi and into a Web page, take a look at some examples doing this using WAMP (an open protocol which runs on top of WebSocket) and Crossbar.io (open source router for WAMP) - http://crossbar.io/iotcookbook/Raspberry-Pi/

Full disclosure: I'm working on these projects - but they are open source, and a great fit for what the OP wants to do.